# Add Texture Over Custom Material And Object Three.js

Tags: three.js, textures, texture-mapping

in the below codes, I imported object and material from Marvelous designer and I can use them. Now I want add texture(.jpg file) over that mateerial and object. How can I do that?

```
  const objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
  const mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
  mtlLoader.setMaterialOptions({side:THREE.DoubleSide});
                    //loaded material here
        mtlLoader.load( 'mrv_shirt6.mtl', function( materials ) {
            materials.preload();
                            //loaded object here
            objLoader.setMaterials( materials );
            objLoader.load( 'mrv_shirt6.obj', function ( object ) {
                object.position.set( 0, -4.2, 0 );
                scene.add( object );
            },
    // onProgress callback
    function ( xhr ) {
        console.log( (xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100) + '% loaded' );
    },

    // onError callback
    function ( err ) {
        console.log( 'An error happened' );
    });
        });

  function render(){
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
    renderer.render(scene,camera);
  }
```

As you can see, I use an imported material and object. Now I want to cover that material and object with my custom texture which is .jpg file.

I tried the below code to load texture but it didnt work as I expected:

```
  const objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
  const mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
  mtlLoader.setMaterialOptions({side:THREE.DoubleSide});

        mtlLoader.load( 'mrv_shirt6.mtl', function( materials ) {
            materials.preload();

            objLoader.setMaterials( materials );
            objLoader.load( 'mrv_shirt6.obj', function ( object ) {
                object.position.set( 0, -4.2, 0 );

      // texture
      var textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader( );
      texture = textureLoader.load("kumas/kumas1.jpg");
      object.traverse( function ( child ) {
                //if ( child.isMesh ) child.material.map = texture;
                if ( child.isMesh ) child.material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
                        //color:     0x996633,
                        //specular:  0x050505,
                        //shininess: my_shine_value,
                        map:       texture,
                        //side:      THREE.DoubleSide
                });
            } );

                scene.add( object );
            },
    // onProgress callback
    function ( xhr ) {
        console.log( (xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100) + '% loaded' );
    },

    // onError callback
    function ( err ) {
        console.log( 'An error happened' );
    });
        });

  function render(){
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
    renderer.render(scene,camera);
  }

  render();
```

The above code made change on the color of the material or object BUT I can not see any pattern change, I mean I can not see pattern of the texture over the object. I only see main color of texture is applied to object. SO for example object turns into red, or blue or pink. BUT no pattern or texture only mono-color change.
Looking for your ideas
Thanks

Comment: A reasonable guess is your .obj model does not define vertex uv's.

Comment: Hmm, you are great @WestLangley. I dont know what is UV but I realized that there is a section "Concatanated UV Coordinates", I made a try with these preference selected. ANd now a quarter part of the object shows texture. Interestingly only lower right quarter part shows the correct texture. I am sharing the image that show the correct texture: https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/2/18/265d47d674b3bcb9fb5d3f9aa79b54f5-full.png

Comment: Another reasonable guess would be to try `texture.wrapS = texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;`

Comment: @WestLangley you are wonderful, this is the solution. Thanks so much. Which tutorial do you advice me to read? Can you share me some links realted with threejs , materials and textures. I looked some to threejs documents but it come somehow complicated to me. I am open to your advices. Thanks